# that must be achieved at the Constituent Assembly

Tags: meaning-in-context

From "Ten days that shook the world"...

I can't get the meaning of "that must be achieved Constituent Assembly or no Constituent Assembly: Peace, Land, and Workers' Control of Industry. "
What does that mean? I can't understand the grammar structure of it actually.
It has this sentence "that must be achieved Constituent Assembly or no Constituent Assembly"
but what does that mean? the verb "achieved" followed by just noun phrase?
Does it mean "that must be achieved in Constituent Assembly's way"? or "that must be achieved at the Constituent Assembly meeting"?

And apart from it or due to the fact I couldn't understand this phrase I can't get the meaning of what follows ":" as well.

> To the multiform discontent of the people the "moderate" Socialists
> had one answer: Wait for the Constituent Assembly, which is to meet in
> December. But the masses were not satisfied with that. The Constituent
> Assembly was all well and good; but there were certain definite things
> for which the Russian Revolution had been made, and for which the
> revolutionary martyrs rotted in their stark Brotherhood Grave on Mars
> Field, that must be achieved Constituent Assembly or no Constituent
> Assembly: Peace, Land, and Workers' Control of Industry. The
> Constituent Assembly had been postponed and postponed—would probably
> be postponed again, until the people were calm enough—perhaps to
> modify their demands! At any rate, here were eight months of the
> Revolution gone, and little enough to show for it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*X or no X* may be regarded as an idiom, and functions (as a whole) as an adverbial. The meaning in principle is "irrespective of whether X is present/involved or not"; but in practice it almost always means "despite the presence/involvement of X"

So the clause is:

> that must be achieved [Constituent Assembly or no Constituent Assembly].

and it means something like "that must be achieved even if the Constituent Assembly objects, or vetoes it, or blocks it".

The "X" never takes an article in this expression, even if it is a non-specific countable noun.

Comment: I missed the point of using it without an article; it makes sense since it is in the some specific usage/context; thank you for your detailed answer